# Can Application Insights be used to capture analytics data for an OData service?

Tags: azure, odata, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I haven't seen any documentation that this is not possible.

I did see a [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/wcf-monitoring-with-application-insights/) about using App-Insights with WCF. But this seems buggy based on the comments.

Using the App-Insights SDK I do not see why this is not possible.

Comment: You might want to try it before claiming it's buggy (most of the time it is not working correctly is just an issue with configuration). That said, I'd love to know what you're looking for specifically in monitoring OData services. What kind of telemetry do you want to get?

Comment: Number of hits, response times, API calls, ...etc. I want to see the same things from app insights as I would from a website.

Comment: I ran some tests, and it does work fine. If you can give it a try, and let us know any feedback on improvements you'd like to see for OData Services, I'd appreciate it. You can provide any feedback on the GitHub project page at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/issues